# Fetch clients without recent order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have an online ordering feature in my app and I'd like to pull all `:clients` that have **not** submitted an order within the last week (I have a field `:submitted_at` to track this).

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client
    scope :within_last_week, -> { where("submitted_at >= ?", 1.week.ago )}
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders
end
```

I almost want to be able to use this `:within_last_week` scope and return clients whose `orders.within_last_week` is empty.

**Is there a way to do this without looping through all clients?**

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to solve this issue, by combining orders and clients in one relation while setting the client relationships to **left_outer_joins** to get all clients even those without orders:

```
Order.left_outer_joins(:client).select("clients.name, SUM(CASE WHEN submitted_at >= '12/01/2019' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_orders").having("total_orders = 0").group("clients.id")
```

**Another way:**

```
Order.left_outer_joins(:client).where("orders.submitted_at >= '12/01/2019' ").having("SUM(orders.id) = 0").group("clients.id")
```

Comment: When I try that in my console I get an error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?"
LINE 1: ...= '12/01/2019' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_orders ? FROM "or...`

Comment: Now I get the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_orders" does not exist
LINE 1: ...."deleted_at" IS NULL GROUP BY clients.id HAVING (total_orde...`

Comment: Still getting an error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_orders" does not exist
LINE 1: ...."deleted_at" IS NULL GROUP BY clients.id HAVING (total_orde...`

Comment: @JeremyThomas I am not sure why the first one is making an issue, I have replaced the single quote with a double quote. I have also added another way to solve it.

Comment: Hmm.. they are both still failing in the console.  The second has the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "orders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "clients" O..`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188233/discussion-between-shiko-and-jeremy-thomas).